# Force on a loop

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

Is magnetic force on a closed loop placed in an magnetic field always zero or does it depend on other factors?

Please also discuss cases in which magnetic force on loop is not zero.

Answer (score 2):

In uniform magnetic field cases,

When the magnetic moment vector is perpendicular to the magnetic field, the net force on a current loop is zero. There will be a net torque, however.

When the magnetic moment vector is parallel to the magnetic field, the net force will still be zero, but will tend to expand the loop. The net torque will be zero.

When the magnetic moment vector is anti-parallel to the magnetic field, the net force will still be zero, but will tend to contract the loop. The net torque will be zero, but this is the configuration where the magnetic potential energy is greatest, as opposed to the parallel configuration, where it is the least.

In summary, yes in a uniform field, the net force on a loop is zero. In non-uniform fields, it depends on how the field varies in space.

Answer (score -1):

It is zero when the field is uniform